# How can I set the order of columns in Outlook E-Mail Table view through VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

[image: Outlook E-Mail table columns]

I use Outlook 2019 to manage ten (10) email accounts
I prefer the single-line table view

**GOAL: columns equally arranged on ALL mail folders**
show columns *importance, icon, status, attachment, from, subject, date, size* with same width and order on all inboxes and subfolders (expect the "sent" folders where I want "to" instead of "from").

Existing partial solution:

- I have a VBA script (see below) to read the formatting (which is in `Outlook.Folder.CurrentView.ViewFields`) of a "reference folder" (where I manually arrange things) and then apply it to the currently selected folders
- **it works for column type, width and name**

**One problem remains:**

- this does NOT influence the ordering
- everything is set, but the order is not same as the order in the configuration

[image: right columns but wrong order after running my script]

Question: How can I influence the column order of the `Outlook.Folder.CurrentView.ViewFields` through VBA?

```vb
Sub ApplyReferenceColumnFormatToSelectedFolder()
    
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' read ViewFields of reference folder into dictionary
    
    Dim refFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set refFolder = myNamespace.Folders.Item("myaccount@myprovider.someTLD").Folders.Item("Posteingang")
    
    Dim refFields As Dictionary
    Set refFields = New Dictionary
    
    Dim thisField As Dictionary
    
    ' iterate over all fields and read the relevant config data
    ' result is in two-dimensional dictionary
    I = 1
    For Each refField In refFolder.CurrentView.ViewFields
        Set thisField = New Dictionary
        thisField("Label") = refField.ColumnFormat.Label
        thisField("ViewXMLSchemaName") = refField.ViewXMLSchemaName
        thisField("Width") = refField.ColumnFormat.Width
        thisField("FieldFormat") = refField.ColumnFormat.FieldFormat
        Set refFields(I) = thisField
        I = I + 1
    Next
    
    ' now "copy" this config to currently selected folder
    
    Set curFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set curView = curFolder.CurrentView
    
    ' remove all but one ViewFields
    ' (ideally, would remove all but there needs to be at least one remaining)
    oC = curView.ViewFields.Count
    If (oC > 1) Then
        For I = oC To 2 Step -1
            curView.ViewFields.Remove (I)
        Next
    End If
    curView.Apply
     
     
    ' now, set the desired configuration
    
    With curView
        ' set single-line table view without preview
        .AutoPreview = olAutoPreviewNone
        .MultiLine = olAlwaysSingleLine
        .ShowFullConversations = True
        '.Apply
     
        ' iterate over the columns form reference folder
        I = 1
        For Each refField In refFields
            Set thisField = refFields(refField)
            
            ' add field
            ' note: can fail, if field of same type already exists
            ' then, we can just "resume next" without adding :-)
            On Error Resume Next
            .ViewFields.Add (thisField("ViewXMLSchemaName"))
            .Apply
            
            ' finally, set the relevant properties
            .ViewFields.Item(I).ColumnFormat.Label = thisField("Label")
            .ViewFields.Item(I).ColumnFormat.Width = thisField("Width")
            .ViewFields.Item(I).ColumnFormat.FieldFormat = thisField("FieldFormat")
            .Apply
            
            I = I + 1
        Next
    End With

    curView.Apply
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.viewfields) has the following remark:

> In a table view, the order of ViewField objects in the ViewFields
> collection is not the same as the order that field columns are
> displayed in the table view. A workaround to obtain the column order
> is to parse the string returned by the View.XML property.

So it doesn't look like you can influence the column order simply by how you arrange the ViewFields collection. It look likes you would need to manipulate the XML.

Have you considered simply creating your desired view, locking that view via VBA (to prevent accidentally altering it), and then applying that view to the various folders?

Sorry that this isn't much of an answer, more of a remark, but it was too long to put in a comment.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the answer. You are right, I am actually using the feature you suggested for a long time and still. It covers 70% of my requirements but some folders deserve a customized view (example: in the "Sent" folder, I want the "TO" and not the "FROM" column), so I am looking for the "one-click" solution.